# Accessing session parameters in Pundit policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, pundit

It appears that Pundit policy does not access session parameters. As constructs does not reconize session as a valid variable or method. Is there any way to access session or other params?

```
class MyModelPolicy
  def create?
    @contructs = Construct.where(['id = ?', session[:construct_id]]).all
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is this line in your code? A controller?

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment. The line would be in the ModelName_policy.rb.

Answer (score 26):

I'm a contributor to Pundit. Policies by default only has access to the current user and the record you're checking permissions for.

You can use the [context pattern defined in the Pundit docs](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#additional-context). Start with creating a user context class in your `app/model` directory accepting all the contextual parameters you need, in this case `session`.

```
class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :session

  def initialize(user, session)
    @user = user
    @session = session
  end
end
```

Then you can override the user record used by pundit with an instance of your `UserContext` class.

```
class ApplicationController
  include Pundit

  def pundit_user
    UserContext.new(current_user, session)
  end
end
```

Finish by making your application policy accept the context. If you want to stay compliant with your old policies, delegate those methods to the context.

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :context, :user, :session

  def initialize(context, record)
    @context = context
    @record = record
  end

  delegate :user, to: :context
  delegate :session, to: :context

  ...

end
```

Now you can access `session` inside your policies.

Comment: What about providing additional context to scopes?

    `def index;         resources = ContextPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, context).resolve;     end`

works but `after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index` triggers `Pundit::PolicyScopingNotPerformedError`. Could I make it work within the Pundit mindset?

Comment: @dira If you use a wrapping class for your user (in this case user context), that context instance will be available inside your policy scope just as it is inside the authorisation methods.

Comment: You're missing the attr_reader for the record. +1 for the answer