# Rails 7 pass session params to pundit policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I'm using Devise to authenticate User in my Rails 7 app and Pundit for authorization. I would like to extend the standard login flow to check if the user has met the 2FA requirements. 2FA is simple and delivered by an external microservice - the user at each login enters the SMS (text message) code he got on his phone.

In a nutshell new login flow should be:

- user authentication via Devise
- allow to authorize if `session[:_2fa] == 'success'`
- redirect to provide_code_path if `session[:_2fa] == 'failed'`

Because the user must go through the 2FA process every time he logs in, I've store such info inside the session params as `session[:_2fa]`. Now to make all the authorization and redirect dance I want to have access to that session to allow or not. I'm aware of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362459/accessing-session-parameters-in-pundit-policy) but it's 7y old so maybe today there is some modern approach instead of creating fake model just to get access to the session?

Code below:

```
# application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :authorized_user

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def authorized_user
    authorize :global, :_2fa_passed?
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = t('errors.user_not_authorized')
    redirect_to provide_code_path
  end
end

# global_policy.rb

class GlobalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def _2fa_passed?
    session[:_2fa] == 'success'
  end
end
```

Comment: Two odd things here stand out to me: (1) Devise is for **authentication** ("do I know you?"); Pundit is for **authorisation** ("are you allowed to do this?"). Two-factor authentication should probably only be relevant to Devise/authentication; it's got nothing to do with Pundit/authorisation. (Unless you have the concept of "logged-in users, who didn't complete 2fa, should have restricted permissions"??!!)

Comment: And (2) this does not look secure. One could just set the cookie: `_2fa = 'success'` and bypass two-factor authentication.

Comment: There are existing/actively maintained libraries for 2fa in rails, such as [this](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor); I'd advise against rolling your own potentially-insecure implementation of something like this, if possible.

Comment: @TomLord Why did you explain me what I already described? lol, that's odd. Anyway, I have to use banking 2FA auth - that's the law, if you think it's better to use some gem instead of secure microservice then well... you're wrong. That's not the point where this `_2fa` will be set (probably it should be inside secure cookies), that's not the point of my question. The question is - is there a better way to pass session params to pundit rather than creating fake model.

Comment: @TomLord And yes, "logged-in users, who didn't complete 2fa, should have restricted permissions" - they should be redirect to the page which they can re-enter the code they received by text message. It's all in my question.

Comment: You did *not* say "my implementation has a big security hole"  Setting a cookie as "secure" does not prevent a user from setting it themselves.

Comment: My point wasn't "you shouldn't use [insert library here]", or "you should use [insert library here]". My point was "you should not add a back-door to bypass the security check, like `session[:_2fa] == 'success'`". This is like locking the door but leaving the window open.

Comment: You can create a custom policy initialiser that takes the `session` variable, or even the `session[:_2fa]` value directly -- policies are just plain ruby objects: https://github.com/varvet/pundit#policies

Comment: But besides, as I wrote above, this is really an *authentication* check not an *authorisation* check -- so you might as well forget about `pundit` and just add in `ApplicationController`: `before_action ... raise No2FAError unless session[:_2fa] == 'true'`

Comment: But I'm reluctant to post that as a "solution", because it's trivial to bypass. For a **bank**, of all things, that's an unacceptable security vulnerability.

Comment: @TomLord the question does not refer to use of `cookies[:_2fa]`, it refers to `session[:_2fa]` which is usually stored in encrypted cookie store and hence is not readable or modifiable without session encryption key. So it's not "trivial to bypass".

Answer (score 0):

Pundit documents this in [Additional Context](https://rubydoc.info/gems/pundit#additional-context) section of the readme.

Instead of user instance you can pass pundit user context object which would hold user instance and extra session context like 2FA authentication status.

```rb
class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :second_factor_authenticated

  def initialize(user, second_factor_authenticated)
    @user = user
    @second_factor_authenticated = second_factor_authenticated
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  include Pundit::Authorization

  def pundit_user
    second_factor_authenticated = session[:_2fa] == 'success'
    UserContext.new(current_user, second_factor_authenticated)
  end
end
```

Then in policy classes rename your `user` attribute to `context` and refer to user instance through `context.user` and 2FA status through `context.second_factor_authenticated`.

So to answer the question - seven years later it is still perfectly acceptable solution.

Given you're using Devise an alternative could be adding ephemeral attribute `second_factor_authenticated` to user class and implementing your own [`.serialize_into_session`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L237-L239) / [`.serialize_from_session`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L241-L244) to store it as part of user "vector" (by default it's only user id + auth salt).